# How to convert SOAP/XML into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

How can I convert this into array using PHP?

```
    <NewDataSet>
    <Table>
    <ITEMNO>145</ITEMNO>
    <ITUPC>602686441100</ITUPC>
    <MFGINO>T1B14</MFGINO>
   </Table>
   <Table>
    <ITEMNO>145</ITEMNO>
    <ITUPC>602686441100</ITUPC>
    <MFGINO>T1B14</MFGINO>
   </Table>
   </NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Yeah, you can parse it :) (spoiler: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to change in array. Let me know if you face any issue .

```
 $data='your XML data';
 $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);
        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($array_data);
        print_r('</pre>');
```

Comment: Actually I am using webservices and my xml data comes from there.So I can't use static way to store XML Data into any Variable. So this code is useless for me, Plz provide any other solution.

Comment: @Trius: I am downvoting your question for calling another person's work "useless". Please make more of an effort to be respectful here.